# Indent chapter titles in memoir

Tags: spacing, formatting, memoir

I am using `memoir` with `section` as chapter style. I want to indent chapter style to the right.
Right now I have:

```
Chapter 1

    Text of first paragraph (first line)
Text of first paragraph (rest of paragraph)
```

But I want:

```
    Chapter 1

    Text of first paragraph (first line)
Text of first paragraph (rest of paragraph)
```

What parameter should I change?

Edit:
Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}


\usepackage{indentfirst}
\parindent 1.25cm
\chapterstyle{section}
\secindent\parindent\relax

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\par
test test test test test

\section{Section}
\par
test test test test test

\end{document}
```

@Francis If I use your idea it works but for section title!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
\chapindent\parindent\relax
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\hspace{\chapindent}\chapnumfont \thechapter\space}
```

to the preamble.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\parindent 1.25cm
\chapterstyle{section}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}}

\chapindent\parindent\relax
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\hspace{\chapindent}\chapnumfont \thechapter\space}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[2-3]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't need to indent section or paragraph. I need to indent chapter title. Just the chapter title style is "section"!

Comment: Now with this code works perfect!

Comment: @alchemist_bg:updated.

Comment: Once again works perfect.